# Kafka Streams - floods kafka logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Streams, and I've noticed that it makes my kafka logs a lot of logs messages such as:

```
[2019-04-17 09:06:16,541] INFO [Log partition=my-application-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000076-repartition-0, dir=/opt/kafka/data/logs] Incrementing log start offset to 316423 (kafka.log.Log) [2019-04-17 09:06:16,545] INFO [Log partition=my-application-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000033-repartition-2, dir=/opt/kafka/data/logs] Incrementing log start offset to 3394 (kafka.log.Log) 
[2019-04-17 09:06:16,546] INFO [Log partition=my-application-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000012-repartition-1, dir=/opt/kafka/data/logs] Incrementing log start offset to 3102 (kafka.log.Log) 
[2019-04-17 09:06:16,549] INFO [Log partition=my-application-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000067-repartition-3, dir=/opt/kafka/data/logs] Incrementing log start offset to 4168 (kafka.log.Log) 
[2019-04-17 09:06:16,551] INFO [Log partition=my-application-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000086-repartition-3, dir=/opt/kafka/data/logs] Incrementing log start offset to 329670 (kafka.log.Log)
```

This is really disturbing because I it floods the logs so I cannot see anything else (also consuming resources).

Why does it happen for (some of) the Kafka Streams internal topics, but not for other topics?

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams purges repartition topics aggressively after the data is processed to free up storage space in the Kafka cluster (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150). It's not possible to disable this.

As a workaround, you could reconfigure the repartition topic configuration parameters `segment.bytes` and `segment.ms` and set them to higher values. **Note, that this will make data purging less effective, though, resulting in more disk usage in the Kafka cluster.**

Comment: I created a JIRA for this. Maybe it's possible to improve this in future versions: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8251